# how to get the position of an array item into the switch case

Tags: iphone, switch-statement

hi
  I stored images in an array & i want to get the position of that item. According to the item position Switch case statements should execute. so how to pass the item position into switch case.

looking forward to your valuable reply.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Navya sri, you need to provide more information possibly with some code that you have tried. Question is not complete and difficult to understand.

Comment: Array declaration numimages = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"],
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"two.png"],
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"three.png"],
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"four.png"],
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"five.png"],
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"six.png"],
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"seven.png"],
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"eight.png"],
     //[UIImage imageNamed:@"eight.png"],
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"nine.png"],nil] retain];
 
i want to write switch case based on array values for that how can i write switch case switch(condition){case 0: statement} case1: like this

Answer (score 2):

```
NSUInteger index = [myArray indexOfObject:myImage];

switch (index) {
    case 0:
        ...
        break;
    case 1:
        ...
        break;
    ...
    case NSNotFound:
        ...
        break;
    default:
        ...
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood your question, to get the position of item in an array yo had compare the values with each other.

Comment: No, you simply use [NSArray indexOfObject:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:) or if possible, [NSArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:). The later is faster but only works if you have the exactly same object (pointer) as stored in the array.